# Ubuntu20.04 - Dual boot windows10, grub doesn't show after Windows update 20H2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Just finished installing Ubntu 20.04 with Windows10 successfully.

Windows was installed first (UEFi) and then Ubnutu 20.04.

Installation process was as needed, and so all updates & app installations.

When Windows updated to 20H2, grub's boot menu (when you select if Ubuntu or Windows10 is desired) is not shown anymore, and Windows10 is booting without any delay.

How can I fix it?

Comment: @Nmath BIOS does not supprt with UEFI partition to boot from, but pressing F12 during boot, indeed provided boot selection, including `Ubuntu` and `Windows10 boot manager`. How can I return grub's menu as before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help)

Comment: Also see [Windows 10 update broke my MBR / GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874181/windows-10-update-broke-my-mbr-grub)  and [Windows 10 update ruined my GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186513/windows-10-update-ruined-my-grub-menu).

Comment: @Nmath Sorry, I'm not a native english speaker so I may have described it wrongly. Pressing "F12" is a BIOS command that lets you decide where to boot from (USB, HDD, CD and so). This is not the grub menu. For my surprise, F12 DID gave an option to boot WINDOWS or UBUNTO along with other USB, CD drives). Still I'm trying to get grub's menu back

Comment: @Nmath And how can I control which one boot first? I have no such option (in BIOS setup).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 update ruined my GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186513/windows-10-update-ruined-my-grub-menu)

Comment: @Nmath although it is a i7, it is a 10 yr old laptop. There is no option in BIOS

Comment: @Nmath The fact that F12 did enter a **BIOS menu** that recognise ubnutu & Windows made me dig a bit deeper, and somehow I missed a collapsable menu that.... showed exactly that. Now, when selecting "Ubuntu" as first boot option and saving BIOS settings, grub menu apeared after boot, allowing me to choose desired OS. Thank YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when selecting **"Ubuntu"** as first boot option and saving BIOS settings, grub menu apeared after boot, allowing me to choose desired OS